# iOS OpenGL adding touch rotation to CMMotionManager(accelerometer) Rotation Matrix

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, rotation, accelerometer

I have an OpenGL world that is viewing the inside of a sphere. The camera is at 0,0,0 and is rotating from modelViewMatrix properly using the CMMotionManager(accelerometer) rotation matrix to rotate the modelViewMatrix.

The issue occurs when I try to rotate the world with the touch screen and the CMMotionManager matrix.

I've tried adding the touch screen movement values to the yaw, pitch, roll returned by the CMMotionManager and creating a new modelViewMatrix. I'm close with this, but when I rotated with the touch 90 degrees along the X(roll), or Y(pitch) then spin the phone from landscape to portrait (90 degree yaw rotation) the matrix doesn't rotate properly, it starts rotating what I think is on the x and z axis.

I think the issue is how I calculated the _rotationX and _rotationY from the yaw. I think it needs to be from the yaw/pitch/roll of the current modelViewMatrix, I just cannot figure out this formula/how to calculate the _rotationX and _rotationY with the current modelViewMatrix state.

Code to update the camera:

```
- (void)update
{   
    roll =  motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll + _rotationX;
    pitch = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch + _rotationY + M_PI;//M_PI is to offset to look at front
    yaw = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw; //+ _rotationZ;

    float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
    _projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f),
                                                            -aspect,
                                                            0.2f,   //camera Position
                                                            25.0f);  //view zDistance


    _modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Make(cos(yaw)*cos(pitch), cos(yaw)*sin(pitch)*sin(roll) - sin(yaw)*cos(roll), cos(yaw)*sin(pitch)*cos(roll) + sin(yaw)*sin(roll), 0,
sin(yaw)*cos(pitch), sin(yaw)*sin(pitch)*sin(roll) + cos(yaw)*cos(roll), sin(yaw)*sin(pitch)*cos(roll) - cos(yaw)*sin(roll), 0,
-sin(pitch), cos(pitch)*sin(roll), cos(pitch)*cos(roll), 0,
 0, 0, 0, 1);

    _modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(_projectionMatrix, _modelViewMatrix);
}
```

Code to update touch:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    float distX = [touch locationInView:touch.view].x -
                  [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view].x;
    float distY = [touch locationInView:touch.view].y -
                [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view].y;

    distX *= 0.005;
    distY *= 0.005;
    //Update rotationX and rotationY based off the position of the phone's yaw landscape = 0, portrait = 90deg
    _rotationX += ((fabsf(cos(yaw))*distY + fabsf(sin(yaw))*distY)); 
    _rotationY += (-(fabsf(cos(yaw))*distX + fabsf(sin(yaw))*distX));
```

}

Comment: Hello, maybe you should use  GLKMatrix4Rotate instead, and also i think you need to use the matrix stack

Comment: I've got it nearly working with GLKMatrix4Rotate. The only issues is that when I turn the phone to my left and try to touch rotate, it simple spins the screen instead of rotating in the direction I would like it too.

I've added just after GLKMatrix4Make:


    _modelViewMatrix =GLKMatrix4Rotate(_modelViewMatrix,_rotationX, 0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    _modelViewMatrix =GLKMatrix4Rotate(_modelViewMatrix,_rotationY,cos(_rotationX),0.0f,sin(_rotationX));

and the rotation is now calculated with:

    _rotationX +=cos(yaw) *distX + (sin(yaw)) *distY;
    _rotationY +=-sin(yaw) *distX + (cos(yaw)) *distY;